# Synthetic individual data using summary-level data

Tags: virtual, synthetic

I have been searching for information on creating a synthetic cohort using summary-level data from published observational studies (effectiveness studies), but I've not found an adequate solution.

One can obtain summary statistics from most observational studies (usually Table 1) and, if you are lucky, some correlation data.

Does somebody create some synthetic data from such information? Is there a package that I can use? I'd really appreciate it if you could give a hint on that.

Thank you!

I've been searching for such information, but most methods require seed data. I'm expecting to come across someone who has already created this kind of data